# moxtra - is it possible to customize chat in ios

Tags: ios

I wanted to add `UIButtons` to the moxtra chat so that the integration can be more seamless. 
Is this possible?
Also the ios docs seem to be not updated -- the create chat method isn't up to date.

Also is it possible to get the data the user is sending in the chat. I want to do certain things based on what they are chatting about.

Comment: or is it possible to make the openchat in a subview? so i can add to it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the current version you cannot add UIButtons to the Moxtra chat UI. This is something that we are working on and will be available in our future version.

The chat SDK documentation for invite options were updated earlier today - https://developer.moxtra.com/moxo/docs-ios-sdk/#moxtra-chat

You can retrieve the chat content using the REST API - "Get Binder Conversations". Youc an find the details about this API under this section https://developer.moxtra.com/moxo/docs-rest-api/#binder-apis

Comment: Thanks!
I am new to ios and I wanted to use the MXChatdelegate to notify me when a change has happened to the binder and then i look up the conversation via the api you pointed to and then do an action. Can you help me in the right direction on how to do this?